# Watson conversation - context - previous input text

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

During a conversation sequence, when an user provides an input for a response coming from the conversation service based on his/her previous question, I am building a new request to the conversation service by passing the previous question as input text and the previous context.

The previous context is to let the Conversation service know the conversation id. The previous input text (question) is to let the Conversation service identify and resume from where it was left (the right dialog node).

**My application uses the user input for validation and updating the context**. For instance, setting the context as user "verified" etc.

My application gets the previous input text from the context object of conversation service.

Could you please let me know if i am doing right?

Comment: Are you hitting with any error?

Comment: Hi Riya, I am not getting any error. This works fine. I only wanted to know if the approach of storing the original input text of the user in the context of the application and using it in the subsequent requests is right approach?

Comment: Yeah,the approach is correct!

Comment: Thanks Riya for validating my understanding.